# How much does Mr. Homn's case weigh?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

Both Commander Riker and Captain Picard struggled to lift and carry Mr. Homn's case. Based on the strength of these Enterprise officers, what is a reasonable weight for it?

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&ei=XScSVMiQCuOQ7AaH34GgDw&url=http://contrails.iit.edu/DigitalCollection/1966/AMRLTR66-017.pdf&cd=1&ved=0CB8QFjAA&usg=AFQjCNGiit8WGNrjccBK8PTThcuu1sOPiQ&sig2=s_JwU2VAbrRJCDSFoLyPjA - Assuming they're both in good physical condition, anything above 100 lbs would be difficult to carry one-handed

Comment: This appears to be a question about human physiology. There are better sources of information for this kind of question than a scifi website.

Comment: And as far as I know, there's no indication that average human strength is the same as it is now.  Benefits of better medical science and all..

Comment: Also, is their "gravity" exactly the same as Earth's?

Comment: How much does it weigh is not opinion based. A canon answer should be available or if not a solid extrapolation to arrive at a reasonable weight can be employed.

Comment: It weighs "it's funny" pounds.

Comment: @meatrademark - The TNG manual says that the Enterprise has 1g of gravity (Earth -normal)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We don't know how strong Mr. Homn is but we have a reasonable expectation of human strength. I would say that based on the strength of the average human male in good shape (and their obvious effort at carrying the case while struggling to seem 'normal' or 'casual') that the case would be approximately 65 to 80 kilograms.

Comment: I wonder if Worf or Spock could carry the case "casually." Data certainly could, of course.

Comment: They could probably pull it off for a few dozen meters but would quickly tire and start to struggle but Data could do it while holding his little pinky out.

Comment: Worf I can definitely see struggling, as his Klingon pride wouldn't allow him to put down the case and admit that it's too heavy. Vulcans would probably put the case down before it was obvious they were having a problem, unless they were compelled to carry it, for whatever reason.